# Renamed my website (URL) – how do I rename all within-page links to the old URL?

Tags: urls, links, migration

A while ago I renamed my website from ExplainingProgress.com to OurWorldInData.org .

My problem is that sometimes – for some IFrames and some images – the URL that is linked to is still the old one (ExplainingProgress.com).

An example are the IFrames on this page: http://www.ourworldindata.org/data/war-peace/war-and-peace-after-1945/

Is there a way of renaming all these internal links automatically or do I have to read through all the HTML and rename it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin called Velvet Blues Update URLs. I use it all the time.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am not sure on what method you followed to rename domain name 
but the standard method what i followed  is

1.Download the Sql file from old database 
2.renamed the domain name from old to new in your case 
  ExplainingProgress.com to OurWorldInData.org 
  use an code editor for simple find and replace
3.uploaded the new sql file to the server 
4. Dont forget to refresh permalinks

@ missing links/images

use this plugin 
[Broken link checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/)

Answer (score 1):

Data in the WP database is serialized. If you just do a search and replace you'll break your site.

You need to reserialize your data as you change it.

There are scripts and services that allow you to do a proper Search and Replace.

My tool of choice is [this one](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), and it works perfectly. There are also a couple plugins that work (like velvet blues), and I also found [this](http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/) service from a theme creation company that does the same thing; which allows you to do the search and replace without actually installing anything on your machine.

Good luck and happy wordpressing.

Comment: Only some data with urls are serialized and it is not "pure" WP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql command as:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');
```

and

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Please try on a test site before!!!